# Python: Appending a list doesn't actually append it?

Tags: python, csv, append

I have a CSV file with names and scores in it. I've made each line a separate list but when appending a variable to this list it doesn't actually do it.
My code is:

```
import csv
f = open('1scores.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
newlist = []
for row in csv_f:
    newlist.append(row[0:4])

    minimum = min(row[1:4])
    newlist.append(minimum)
print(newlist)
```

With the data in the file being

```
Person One,4,7,4
Person Two,1,4,2
Person Three,3,4,1
Person Four,2
```

Surely the output would be `['Person One', '4', '7', '4', '4']` as the minimum is 4, which I'm appending to the list. But I get this: `['Person One', '4', '7', '4'], '4',`
What am I doing wrong? I want the minimum to be inside the list, instead of outside but don't understand.

Comment: You are appending a list  with `row[0:4]`, append to that list if you want the min to be in it, also you should be using `min(row[1:4],key=int)`

Comment: There I was just reading there data from the file to make a list. I wanted to add more values to that list.

Answer (score 1):

Append the min to each row and then append the row itself, you are appending the list you slice first then adding the min value to newlist not to the sliced list:

```
for row in csv_f:
    row.append(min(row[1:],key=int)
    newlist.append(row)
```

You could also use a list comp:

```
new_list =  [row + [min(row[1:], key=int)] for row in csv_f]
```

You also need the, `key=int` or you might find you get strange results as your scores/strings will be compared lexicographically:

```
In [1]: l = ["100" , "2"] 

In [2]: min(l)
Out[2]: '100'

In [3]: min(l,key=int)
Out[3]: '2'
```